# When bot is run throuh Studio, Firefox is launched, but through Orchestrator IE launched

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have set the Browser Type as Firefox in Uipath studio (both for Open Browser and Attach Browser activities). Also default browser in the system is Firefox.
Now, when the bot is run from UIPath, Firefox is launching. But when I run the same bot through Orchestrator,IE is launching.
I did not find any browser setting in Orchestrator community edition.
Please help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Orchestrator is UiPath's server-based application that allows you to manage, schedule, and execute your robots. It does not provide functionality to modify processes/sequences that are built in Studio.

What this sounds like is that you have initially published your package from Studio to Orchestrator, then you have made further changes to your sequence and activities. One of which was to change the browser from IE to Firefox. You have saved this and ran it locally and it works as expected but have ***not published your latest changes to Orchestrator***.

If you have published again then you probably have forgotten to ***go to Orchestrator and set it to use the latest package***. This is done from the Processes page and not the Packages page. You should see an update icon next to the process that is using an old version, like so:

[image]